# Is calling avaudiorecorder calling from viewdidload bad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I am working with Xcode 6.1.1 and objective-c.

I am using `AVAudioRecorder` to record some audio. 
This is all working great and playing back also works. 
Right now I activate the recording with a button.

What I would like to do is start recording at the end of `viewdidload`.
So I placed the following on the end of the `viewdidload` method:

```
[audiorecorder record];
```

Xcode is not complaining about it and it is working. I hear no difference when using an button or calling it in `viewdidload`. But I still have some bad feelings about doing this.

Question: Is it a good practice using `[audiorecorder record];` on the end of `viewdidload`? Or could this break the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. You could possibly get some lag when the view is loading depending on how you transition to it.

The other option would be to call `- (BOOL)prepareToRecord` in `viewdidload` then call `record` in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` . This would allow all the UI elements to be loaded on the screen before letting `AVAudioRecorder` grab memory.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I was just curious if this could potentially break an app. Many thanks for the info.